# Understanding the basis term

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Consider:
$$\left( {\matrix{
   0 & 1 & 2  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)$$

I want to find a basis for the row-space of the matrix above.

One might say $$B = \left\{ {\left( {\matrix{
   0 & 1 & 2  \cr 
 } } \right)} \right\}$$

But, If we split this vector, we have:

$$B' = \left\{ {\left( {\matrix{
   0 & 1 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right),\left( {\matrix{
   0 & 0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)} \right\}$$

$B'$ vectors are linearly independent and span the row space of the matrix.

So, seemingly we have two bases for the matrix, with different dimensions.
I have certainly missed something fundamental here.

What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $B'$ spans a space strictly larger than the row space of your matrix.  For example $(0,1,3) \in \text{span}\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ but $(0,1,3) \notin \text{span}\{(0,1,2)\}$